# Can't install windows 8.1 - setup stucked

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, windows-8.1, bad-sectors

Recently I got a desktop with a hard disk Toshiba 500GB which has  windows 7 installed on it.

When turning on the computer, windows logo appears and it does not go beyond that. After about 30 minutes the machine shuts down automatically.

---

### What I tried

---

Then tried to install windows 8.1 with a bootable usb and just proceeded with the installation.
The "**install now**" window appears, clicked "install now", then only I can see is "**the setup is loading**" and nothing more.

Kept waiting for about  30 minutes to see if it going be working at some point. But it was not.
Tried many times but had same results.

Then I tried to go to "repair windows" option in the setup but it was also kept loading but nothing happened.

**Strange behavior**

> I put that hard disk into another desktop - which works fine,  and on BIOS set the boot order to the original hard disk it had. 
>   But to my surprise, the computer boots with the windows 7 hard disk. Checked once again the boot order but it was as I had set it before. 
>   But the machine boots with windows 7 hard disk. And even in that, windows 7 does not go beyond windows logo, just as in the first desktop.

After, I removed it and boot with the usual drive, then desktop loaded, I plugged the hard disk (faulty one) and went to disk management, clicked "Rescan disks". The disk management window was not responding and task manager showed the **hard disk (faulty one) 100% active time but little or no read or writing activity.**

Then connected the hard disk back to the its own desktop and  I tried with a bootable pen drive with ubuntu 18 LTS and used it in live mode. After about 30 minutes, ubuntu loaded and in disks, showed the hard disk partitions and it showed there was **"890 bad sectors"** on it.

I don't know whether that much bad sectors is to be worried about.

When I try to access the hard disk, I could not able to mount it. Even I could not format it.

I want to take data on that disk if it is not usable.

I'm looking forward to your answers t solve this issue and also possible reasons for that strange behavior.

Comment: The HDD has physical damage to the platters and would be recommended to be replaced.  If you have data on it you'd like to retrieve, connect it to another PC running Windows and run `chkdsk /f /b /x <driveletter>:` prior to copying any data off of it, but the HDD should not be used beyond that, else you risk repeated data corruption.

Comment: I suggest you get a carrier for the hard drive (Amazon), put the hard drive in the carrier, attach it to a working PC, and then see what data you can get from it. Will the computer above run Windows 10?  It is past time to be trying to run Windows 8.

Comment: @JW0914 I can't connect and run ````chkdsk```` because my machine gets stucked once I connected it.

Comment: @infinitecode You'll have a better chance connecting it while booted to WinPE [install USB] or WinRE  to run `chkdsk` on it _(don't use any Linux repair tools to repair an NTFS partition, as they're subpar to `chkdsk`)_.  You can use recovery software like [`TestDisk`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover the data without running `chkdsk`, however you have a better chance of that data not being corrupted if you run `chkdsk` first. There are also bootable DOS utilities that do a scan of the HDD and mark bad sectors as unusable, but I'm not sure how that affects data recovery.

Comment: @JW0914 Okay, I'll try, Can you give me any reasons to that strange behavior I have described above in my question?

Comment: @infinitecode I did in my first comment - HDD has physical damage to the platters - so when Windows tries to access the disk, it's having issues doing so due to the physical damage, which in turn results with the OS hanging and any OS install to the disk to either fail outright or hang during install.

Comment: @infinitecode You can get a better understanding of just how much physical damage has been done by using `smartctl` to access the S.M.A.R.T data on Linux: Boot an Ubuntu Install USB > Choose Try Ubuntu > Open a terminal via `CTRL`+`ALT`+`T` > `sudo apt-get update` > `sudo apt-get install smartmontools` > Get S.M.A.R.T. data: `sudo smartctl -a /dev/<disk>` > Run a long S.M.A.R.T. test: `sudo smartctl -t long /dev/disk` _(can check progress periodically via `sudo smartctl -a /dev/<disk> | grep progress`)_ > View S.M.A.R.T test results: `sudo smartctl -a /dev/<disk>`

Comment: @JW0914 I tried to do ´´´´chkdsk´´´´ in WinPE but didn't work. Even hard disk connected after loaded windows repair tool didn't work. Tried DLC Boot also but no luck.(i'm not an expert enough on that tools).... Even in ubuntu before, accessing that hard disk sometimes hangs.... could not even run some general test(not remember names - but had S.M.A.R.T thing)

Comment: Replace the drive and be done with it.